# Expected interarrival time

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> Given that there are 40 arrival times in 3 hours which are uniformly distributed on $(0,3)$, what is the expected time till the tenth arrival?

My book says that the answer should be as follows:

> The expected interarrival time is $\frac{3}{41}$, so the time till the tenth arrival has an expected value of $\frac{30}{41}$.

This might be a very basic question, but why is the expected interarrival time $\frac{3}{41}$, and not $\frac{3}{40}$?

Comment: Is $U(0,3)$ the distribution of the arrival times or interarrival times? It seems like there should be some more context to this question, because it is very confusing as written.

Comment: @Math1000 Of the arrival times.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question. If the arrival time has $U(0,3)$ distribution, then the expected time of the first arrival would be $\frac32$. Is that the entire question or is there any more detail you can provide?

Comment: @Math1000 The question means that the 10 arrival times are jointly distributed on $(0,3)$, i.e. that there are 10 arrivals in the $(0,3)$ interval at a uniform distance from each other (so therefore I thought the expected value would be $3/40$. But I agree that the question is badly formulated (but I didn't design it).

Comment: Oh, it makes a lot more sense now! Originally there was no mention of 40 arrivals...

Answer (score 3):

Occurrences that are uniformly distributed in time indicate the arrival process is Poisson. The estimate of the arrival rate $\lambda$ would be $$\hat \lambda = {40 \over 3}$$

The estimated mean interarrival time would then be ${{3} \over {40}}$ and the estimated expected time until the 10th arrival would be ${{3} \over {4}}$ as you thought.

Comment: I was going to post a more technical answer that boils down to this (which is correct).

Answer (score 1):

I think the book answer is incorrect. However, here is a possible way to replicate it. If 2 arrivals occurred in $[0,3],$ you could estimate the interarrival time as ${1},$ correct? There are $n+1$ interarrival times for $n$ events (I am guessing at what the question is wanting you to assume.)

Then the expected interarrival time would be $3 \over 41$, as the book says, and the expected time until the 10th arrival would by $30 \over 41$.

Comment: I don't see how there are $n+1$ interarrival times for $n$ events. If $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n$ are the arrival times, then $T_1, T_2-T_1, \ldots, T_n - T_{n-1}$ are the interarrival times - and clearly there are $n$ of those.

Comment: What about (for this example) $3 - T_n$?

Comment: Assuming that the 41st arrival is at time 3, sure. But otherwise no.

Comment: I agree with you and believe this approach is incorrect. I will post another answer.